# Как из файла считать данные, например (7 13 41 213 41) и поместить в массив int?

Tags: c#

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
int[] a = new int[10];
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
   obj.SetText(File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName)); 
}
```

Этот код открывает файл и помещает все данные в Textbox-формы. В текстовом файле хранятся данные как описал в топике. Как считать эти данные не в строку, а в массив инт ?

Comment: считать как строку, разделить на отдельные числа (string.Split), преобразовать числа в int (int.Parse) и положить в массив. Документацию на упомянутые функции думаю сами найдете

Answer (score 1):

В твоём массиве `int[] a = new int[10];` могут храниться только int

Если в файле есть данные другого типа `7 13 41 213 41 dsdhsj` то будет ошибка.  Добавлено `try` - теперь при наличии данных другого типа создание массива не произойдёт.

```
        // Configure open file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show open file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            var a2 = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            try
            {
                int[] a = a2.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

                //дальше добавляешь что тебе нужно 
                //  obj.SetText(File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName)); 
            }
            catch { }

        }
```

Можно использовать:

```
int[] a = textBox1.Text.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Или

```
int[] a = textBox1.Text.Split(' ').
          Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( x )).
          Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Или

```
int[] result = textBox1.Text.Split( new[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Или

```
text.Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: все хорошо, но есть 2 момента. Вариант без LINQ, все таки с LINQ, Select - это расширение как раз оттуда. И второе, int.Parse() при неправильной входной строке упадет с исключением. Стоит упомянуть этот факт в ответе. Для олимпиадного решения подойдет, для практического не очень.

Comment: Постоянно выпадает ошибка System.FormatException. Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: дополните свой код и укажите на какой строке ошибка

Comment: обновлён ответ.